# MySQL query to determine if a number is greater than a VARCHAR containing a negative value

Tags: php, mysql, web

For a project, I'm storing location points in my MySQL database.  The latitude and longitude data for each point is stored as a varchar.  It must remain a varchar for reasons I won't get in to.  For each new point, I'm trying to perform a search to see if there's already any point in my database within a .000300 latitude/longitude radius of the new point.

My PHP code is as follows:  ($lat and $long are the new point's latitude and longitude)

```
$lat1 = $lat - 0.000300;
$lat2 = $lat + 0.000300;
$long1 = $long - 0.000300;
$long2 = $long + 0.000300;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `DataBase`.`DataBase_data` WHERE `DataBase_data`.`Type`='Point' AND `DataBase_data`.`Lat`>'$lat1' AND `DataBase_data`.`Lat`<'$lat2' AND `DataBase_data`.`Long`>'$long1' AND `DataBase_data`.`Long`<'$long2'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_error();
```

The code works correctly when both latitude and longitude are positive numbers.  However, when one (or both) of them are negative numbers, the search doesn't work.  I think it has something to do with doing a "greater than" and "less than" comparison with a varchar containing a - sign, but I'm not positive.  Any ideas about how to fix the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simple solution is to __not__ use varchar for storing numbers

Comment: And even better solution is to use a spatial extension. It's not that trivial to work with coordinates with `>` and `<`

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the negative numbers look like?  And examples of mismatches?

Answer (score 3):

This is your query

```
SELECT d.*
FROM `DataBase`.`DataBase_data` d
WHERE d.`Type`='Point' AND d.`Lat`> '$lat1' AND d.`Lat`<'$lat2' AND
      d.`Long`>'$long1' AND d.`Long`<'$long2';
```

My first suggestion is to do the comparison as numbers.  You can convert to a number easily in MySQL by adding 0:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM `DataBase`.`DataBase_data` d
WHERE d.`Type` = 'Point' AND (d.`Lat` + 0) > $lat1 AND (d.`Lat` + 0) < $lat2 AND
      (d.`Long` + 0) > $long1 AND (d.`Long` + 0) < $long2;
```

Does this fix your problem?

Comment: This fixed the problem!  Thanks a lot.  I knew there was probably some easy way to convert the VARCHAR to a number.  I was thinking of casting it as another data type, but your solution is much simpler.

Comment: Mark this as the answer then :)